# How to use combobox's first store value as default value EXTJS

Tags: arrays, extjs

I need to use whatever the first value appears in the combobox 
Using values directly like this one

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Type',
name: 'type',
store: [
    'Bike'
    'Car',
    'Truck'
],
value: 'Bike' // this value
```

It's easy because the first value is given, but I need it dynamic like this one below

```
xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Type',
name: 'type',
store: this.type,
// value
```

It takes the type from the database so I won't know the first value in the combobox

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Store's **load event** to do action on dataload. After that you can use ComboBox's

> select method

to set value.

**Here is working code:**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Parent Panel',
            frame: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 500,
            width: 400,

            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },

            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: states,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'abbr',
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function(combo) {
                        combo.store.on('load', function(store, records) {
                            combo.select(records[0]);
                            console.log(combo, records);
                        });
                        combo.store.load();
                    }
                }
            }],

            collapsible: true
        });
    }
});
```

**Here is working fiddle link:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kgg